# Notifications using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook recently made access to the user's notifications using the Graph API possible. Using the Graph API we should now be able to mark a notification as read.

I used the REST API to mark notifications as read before without any problems and now I would like to use the Graph API instead. I am making the following request:

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"notifications" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

And the `params` dictionary will look like this:

```
{
    id = xxxxxxxx;
    unread = 0;
}
```

I am getting the following error:

> **OAuthException:** (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.

Does anyone have an idea why I might be getting this error?

Comment: could you help me this problem?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11516912/mark-notification-as-read-with-facebook-api-in-ios
thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was happened because I was using the `notification_id` which FQL returned but it seems that the Graph API returns another type of ID. E.g. `notif_xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx` and the request should look like:

`[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"notif_xxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxx" andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];`

With the `params` dictionary being:

```
{
    unread = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you request the correct permission??

```
manage_notifications    

Enables your app to read notifications and mark them as read. 
This permission will be required to all access to notifications after October 22, 2011.
```

Comment: Yes, I just checked my profile. It shows that my application does have the `manage_notifications` permission. "**May access my notifications and may mark them as read**"

Comment: Try to do in directly. Point your browser to `http://graph.facebook.com/id/notifications?access_token=...` and see what Facebook returns.