# Mark notification as read with Facebook API in iOS

Tags: facebook-graph-api, notifications

I have referenced a few problems about this issue on StackOverflow, but nothing seems to work.

**Code:**

```
NSMutableDictionary *dc = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"0", @"unread", nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"21306691" andParams:dc andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

`21306691` is the `notification_id`. I am sure that I have `manage_notifications` permission.

Please help me, thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you post your stacktrace please so we know what the problem is?

Comment: +1 Let's cut some slack here alright. A down vote for poor language skills is just rude.

Answer (score 2):

```
notif_recipient_id_notificationid
```

Where `notif` is a key word, 
`recipient_id` is id of logged in facebook user
`notificationid` is the id of notification (which you got).

Use the above pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I think your Notification ID is wrong! I get a format like this: `notif_524065381_15010202` for Notification IDs!

Always check with [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer) to see if your Facebook request works, if yes, then look at your code!

Comment: Btw I don't know how you get the notifications, but to get the array of unread notifications you can use the GraphPath: `me&fields=notification`